# amp-img swallows inline elements very after it

Tags: html, amp-html, google-amp

I'm facing a problem about amp-img.

When I write inline elements after amp-img on source code,
amp-img swallows the elements inside it when browser renders it.

source code `<amp-img /><span>...</span>`
->
rendered html `<amp-img><span>...</span></amp>`

or

source code `<amp-img /><amp-img /><a><amp-img /></a>`
->
rendered html `<amp-img><amp-img><a><amp-img /></a></amp-img></amp-img>`

If I flip the order of the elements like this,

source code `<span>...</span><amp-img />`

It works normally.

I checked with Chrome and Safari on MacOS, Safari on iOS.

Does anybody know the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you post a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<amp-img /><span>...</span>
```

to

```
<amp-img></amp-img><span>...</span>
```